# UiAutomator crashes on Nexus 4 but works fine on emulator

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, android-uiautomator, nexus-4

I am running a very simple test:

```
public class BenchmarkAuto extends UiAutomatorTestCase {
    public void testDemo() throws UiObjectNotFoundException {  
            getUiDevice().pressHome();
            getUiDevice().click(650,461);
    }
```

When I run it on an emulator it runs fine.  When I run it on my Nexus 4 I get the following error (and my devices restarts):

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.android.uiautomator.core.UiDevice.getDisplayWidth(UiDevice.java:379)
    at com.android.uiautomator.core.UiDevice.click(UiDevice.java:407)
    at org.zeroxlab.zeroxbenchmark.test.BenchmarkAuto.testDemo(BenchmarkAuto.java:29)
```

I looked at the UIDevice source code and it looks like this is the culprit:

```
Display display = getAutomatorBridge().getDefaultDisplay();
```

The display is null and causes the NullPointerException two lines later.

Anyone have any idea how to resolve this?

Answer (score 1):

The problem was that I had "Pointer Location" turned on in Developer options.  Turned it off and it works just fine.  Hopefully someone else had the same issue and this helps them :)

Comment: do you have any idea, why "pointer location" causes this crash ?

Comment: no idea. But I don't see why you'd need to have pointer location on when running uiautomator.